# Error: "The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value."

Tags: asp.net, delegates

I have an issue with asp.net and delegates, which is giving me the following error:

```
Date:10/07/2014 11:54:49

Page Name: Global.asax

Source: System.Web
Target Method: ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig
Message: The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value.

Stack Trace:    at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ValidateRequestExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Exactly what error message says. Your query string (total length of your URL) exceeds maximum value. You can configure your site to accept longer query strings or (if you're sending a form) change method from HTTP GET to HTTP POST.

Comment: @devanalysts I edited your question to not only contain unformatted code and removed the plea for help in the title (it's not me, but the community will get angry about that). It's up to you if you want to further edit your question and so be able to get more help. I upvoted your question in the meantime. Thanks! :-)